# PHP If Then statement based on numeric range from field output

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a number field: `<?php echo $entity->field_zip_code_name[0];?>`

I want to create an if then statement based on the output number. Here is what I have:

```
if ($entity->field_areacode[0] = 92919,92923,94975,37783) {
    <h3 style="font-size: 20px;"><strong>Area Code:</strong></h3>;
}
else {
    NONE;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Or at the very least Google 'php if statement'

Comment: ok sorry @ChrisWillard I have added to code the best I could

Comment: @AndyLester I have tried to add what I have..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `x` is, if it's `$entity->field_zip_code_name[0]` then echo that:

```
if(in_array($entity->field_zip_code_name[0], [92919,92923,94975,37783])) {
    //display x
}
```

If your PHP version doesn't support `[]` then use `array()`:

```
if(in_array($entity->field_zip_code_name[0], array(92919,92923,94975,37783))) {
    //display x
}
```